# How to reset nested tree of backbone models

Tags: backbone.js

Below is a code that describes nested tree model, and a sample data in json. 
How do I reset `blocks` with provided `data`?

```
var Block, Blocks, data, blocks;

Block = Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    this.blocks = new Blocks;
  }
});

Blocks = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Block
});

data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    blocks: [
      {id: 2, blocks: [{id: 3}]}, {id: 4}
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 5
  }
];

blocks = new Blocks;
```

Comment: Why does Block contain a Blocks collection? This is a cyclic model. Are you intending that?

Comment: Yes, I need a tree of blocks, where every block has nested blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var Block, Blocks, data, blocks;

Block = Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    // access 'blocks' via attributes
    // and initialize collection by passing the attributes in
    this.attributes.blocks = new Blocks(this.attributes.blocks);
  }
});

Blocks = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Block
});

data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    blocks: [
      { id: 2, 
        blocks: [
          { id: 3 }
        ]
      }, 
      { id: 4 }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 5
  }
];

// initialize blocks by passing 'data' in
blocks = new Blocks(data);​
```

Ok, well, since attributes are stored under `attributes` prior to initialize, you need to call `this.attributes.blocks` in your initialize function to ensure there is no mix-up with `this.blocks` (which there was).

You also need to initialize `blocks` by passing data into it's constructor, which is the same for every other instance of `Blocks`, i.e., those also stored inside each `Block`.

Comment: Thanks, I've just come up with something similar, although I'm storing blocks in `model.blocks` instead of `model.attributes.blocks`.

Comment: I'd be careful of doing that if you don't have a good reason to. Running your initial code snippet, with the correct parameters to constructors but without using this.attributes, you'll see your objects end up with .blocks and .attributes.blocks upon inspection, which may complicate things and generally goes against Backbone conventions.

Comment: In this tip: http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-nested nested collection is not put inside attributes. I think its better to keep attributes structure as a plain json object.

Comment: Ok, but remember that they aren't passing the attributes in through the constructor on that example.

Comment: I will need to make my code work with block.fetch and block.blocks.fetch soon to reload tree branches, right now I'm only bootstrapping it from js object.

Comment: is there a way to save back reference to parent block?